# I am trying to apply media query for background color with max and min width but browser applies query on different dimension

Tags: css, media-queries

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

@media(max-width:400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 2px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:625px) and (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>hello Lorem ipsum, </h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, sit.</p>
```

I am just trying to apply media query by keeping max and min-width for background colour but chrome applies query for colour when my min-width is 782px and max-width is 999px?
Any solution?

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Comment: It seems your other css file overrides this. Open dev tools and check again. Only other cause I can think of is that you have zoom in your browser set to 125% so everything is bigger, like 800px becomes 1000px. Change it back to 100%. `ctrl + 0` (zero) will do it.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, you have to define viewport as device-width.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

@media(max-width:400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 2px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:625px) and (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello Lorem ipsum, </h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, sit.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `...but chrome applies query for colour when my min-width is 782px and max-width is 999px` wouldn't that rule out your answer?

Comment: i checked my html file, view port has already been set as device-width

Comment: Don't you use other CSS files like bootstrap?

Comment: @George i am learning plain css , planning to learn flexbox next

Comment: @MrT i couldn't understand your point. i am trying to apply media query for back ground colour when my width is between 625-800px, but when i inspect in dev tools,and changes width it changes background colour between 782-999px